# A function that changes the value of a list without reason

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm stunned with this function I've written for python. I've observed that in the lower `while` it changes the values in the list `vctor` even though that list is not touched along the function. I've passed the pair `(10, [1,3,5,7,10])` and it has changed the list `vctor` to `[1,3,5,8,10]`. Is there an explanation for this?

```
def siguiente(k,vctor):
    l = len(vctor)
    vctorsig = vctor
    i = l-1
    while i>= 0:    
        if vctorsig[i] <= k - l + i: 
            j=i
            while j<=l-1:
                print vctor
                vctorsig[j] = vctor[i]+j-i+1
                j=j+1
            i = -1
        else:
            i = i-1
    return vctorsig
```

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect

Comment: What's the purpose of the `else` clause on the outer `while` loop?  You never do anything with `i` again after that point.

Comment: I don't know why it is displayed like that. In the source text (click edit) it has a better indentation.

Comment: @user17786 It was because you mixed tabs and spaces for indentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `vctorsig = vctor`, you are making `vctorsig` a reference to the list referenced by `vctor`, so when you modify it, you modify the original list.

If you wish to copy the list there, you can simply do `vctorsig = list(vctor)`.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little hard to tell because your indentation is funny, but I think that the line:

```
vctorsig = vctor
```

is your problem.  In this line, you create a new *reference* to the same list.  In other words, if you change `vctorsig` (in this line `vctorsig[j] = vctor[i]+j-i+1`), you also change `vctor` since they are **the same list**.  The easy way out of this is to make a copy:

```
vctorsig = vctor[:]
```